# LocustIO: display logs while writing to log file

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have found a way to [create log files on LocustIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049264/where-can-i-find-locust-logs). It successfully writes all logs in the file.

Is there a way that the terminal display the logs and writes it on the log file as well? Just so I could easily monitor the results without opening the log file every time.

Tried programmatically but still does not print it.

Nothing prints after running `locust -f my_locust_file.py --logfile=locustfile.log`

```
@task(1)
def fetch_records(self):
... 
    response = self.client.get(full_result, auth=login_creds, headers=headers)
    entry_log = "Fetch Records | Username: {}\tPassword: {} | Response: {}".format(self.username, self.password, response)
    logging.info(entry_log)
    print(entry_log)
```

**UPDATE**
Tried using python loggers as well and running `locust -f my_locust_file.py` without `--logfile`. It is displaying in console but not outputting in logfile.

```
def on_start(self):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=my_logfile, level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Add a second handler that logs to stderr.

Comment: Tried the first two here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log-file. Not really familiar with loggers and handlers. Can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted a way from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978464/6428837). Best to place in *class level* so that you wont encounter duplicate logs in the file.

```
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('locustfile.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)

log.info("Fetch Records | Username: {}\tPassword: {} | {}".format(self.username, self.password, response))
```